# Table column width

Tags: javascript, css, angular, html-table

I have a big HTML table (like 50 columns) and each column has 4 possible configurable styles:

- auto (like flex 1) -> 'auto'
- px (number in pixels) -> '100px'
- % (percentage number) -> '10%'
- content (width of the max content of that column) -> 'content'

```html
<table *ngIf="features.length > 0" id="list-tab-table" #listTabTable>
    <colgroup>
        <col *ngFor="let attribute of features[0].getAttributesListView(); let i = index" [ngClass]="{
                'cls-auto': attribute.listviewwidth === 'auto',
                'cls-content': attribute.listviewwidth === 'content',
                'cls-px': attribute.listviewwidth.indexOf('px') > 0,
                'cls-percent': attribute.listviewwidth.indexOf('%') > 0
            }">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr class="label-row">
            <th *ngFor="let attribute of features[0].getAttributesListView()">
                <p>{{attribute.label}}</p>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let feature of features; let i = index">
            <td *ngFor="let attribute of feature.getAttributesListView()" title="{{attribute.value}}">
                <p [innerHTML]="attribute.value"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried everything I know: col elements, table layout, flex items... but nothing seems to cover all options.

All options might happen at once in different columns: column1-auto, column2-200px, column3-content, column4-10%, column5-100px, column6-20%...

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/table-widths

[image]

Comment: can you create a stackbliz?

Comment: added stackbliz. It only has 1 row and random values, but it's enough

Comment: StackBliz updated with my aproach. It uses vw instead of % (I know it's not the same, but the only one that worked) and I think there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below css. It will add horizontal scrollbar to table.

```
#list-tab-table {
    overflow-x: auto;        
}
```

Comment: It's already in auto. But I cannot find a solution that fits all 4 requirements

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear on what your various description are describing but a great deal can be acheieved but dialling in specific properties on the `table` tag and setting widths etc on the `col` elements.

Assuming the number of `col` elements is knowable then percentage widths can be acheived.

A few examples:

I think this is your "auto" option

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: greenyellow;
  width: 100%;
}

col:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: pink;
}

col {}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>columns</th>
      <th>second column</th>
      <th>third column</th>
      <th>fourth column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat id vero debitis nihil ducimus esse!</td>
      <td>more content</td>
      <td>random comment</td>
      <td>more stuff</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The fixed pixel width option

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: greenyellow;
}

col:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: pink;
}

col {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>columns</th>
      <th>second column</th>
      <th>third column</th>
      <th>fourth column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat id vero debitis nihil ducimus esse!</td>
      <td>more content</td>
      <td>random comment</td>
      <td>more stuff</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The % option:

```css
table {
  border:1px solid grey;
  background: greenyellow;
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed
}


col:nth-of-type(2n) {
background: pink;
}

col:nth-child(2) {
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>columns</th>
      <th>second column</th>
      <th>third column</th>
      <th>fourth column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat id vero debitis nihil ducimus esse!</td>
      <td>more content</td>
      <td>random comment</td>
      <td>more stuff</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The content determines option:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: greenyellow;
}

col:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: pink;
}

col {}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>columns</th>
      <th>second column</th>
      <th>third column</th>
      <th>fourth column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur </td>
      <td>more content</td>
      <td>random comment</td>
      <td>more stuff</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: When you have like...50 columns, it all breaks. I will update the question. When the table overflows the width percentages no longer work.